# MapBox regionDidChangeAnimated fired multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, location

I really hope you can help me. I'm using MapBox and also an "Augmented Reality" piece of code (https://github.com/DanijelHuis/HDAugmentedReality).

It works in a way that I have a tab bar controller with the following tabs:

1. Tab that has MapBox in it
2. Tab that has a View Controller I created which calls the ARViewController (which is the code I got from GitHub)

Now my problem is really inconsistent, for some reason at some point when I move to the 2nd tab the regionDidChangeAnimated which is in my 1st tab stars running endlessly.

I know that the regionDidChangeAnimated function is called only in 2 situations:
1. User change the region on the map
2. Some code change the center / region of the map

But I couldn't find anywhere something that will change the region / center of the map.

Any guidance of what can cause this thing will be much appreciated.

Thank you!

PS - I didn't add any piece of code because I'm not even sure what piece of code might cause it.

Answer (score 0):

mapView(_:regionDidChangeAnimated:)

"This method is called whenever the currently displayed map region changes. During scrolling, this method may be called many times to report updates to the map position"

Map region is updated after calling one of following methods:

1 - setRegion(_:animated:)

2 - showAnnotations(_:animated:)

However:  setCenter(_:animated:) doesn't change the zoom level means no regionDidChangeAnimated call back